# How to force Html::submitButton to look like Html::a link in Yii2

Tags: html, yii2, glyph

I am trying to customize a submitButton in Yii2 with use of glyphicons.
The following code represents what I need at the end:

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true"></span>', ['handshake', 'id' => $model->id]);?>
```

I tried:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>', ['id' => $model->id]) ?>
```

but it gives me a button default frame with icon inside. But I just need an icon. How can I disable the standard button frame?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a class for this `btn-link`

```
Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>', ['id' => $model->id, 'class' => 'btn btn-link'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these ways:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('', ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-bell']) ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?= Html::submitButton('text', ['class' => 'btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-bell']) ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?= Html::submitButton('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> text', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>', ['id' => $model->id,'class'=>'linkbutton']) ?>
```

and add css to your stylesheet

```
.linkbutton{
     background:none!important;
     border:none; 
     padding:0!important;
     font: inherit;
     /*border is optional*/
     border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well , if you only need an icon**

```
<?= Html::tag('span', '', [
   'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-bell' ,
   'aria-hidden' => true,
   'onclick' => "$('#YOUR_FORM_ID').yiiActiveForm('submitForm')" , 'cursor'
 ])?>
```

**If you need an 'a' tag**

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true"></span>','',
    ['class' => 'sub_link'])?>
```

Script would be

```
$(document).on('click','.sub_link',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#YOUR_FORM_ID').yiiActiveForm('submitForm');
});
```